# Разделить строку на 4 разных значения в C#

Tags: c#, сортировка

Нужно создать программу для сортировки, но для начала нужно забить строку на разные переменные.
Считывает строки из файла(Сделал), добавляет их в array(Сделал), а теперь чтобы их можно было сортировать нужно разбить строку на 4 переменных.
Пример:

```
Bruce Wayne,    123456, 25.88, 35.50
string a = "Bruce Wayne";
int b = 123456;
decimal c = 25.88;
double d = 35.50;
```

Как это лучше сделать чтобы потом использовать для сортировки по заданным параметрам?
Спасибо.

upd.

```
Employee[] employeesArray = new Employee[100];
FileStream file = new FileStream("employees.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file);
string line;
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null){
            
Console.WriteLine(line);
string[] emp = line.Split(',');
// creating an Empolyee object
employeesArray[0] = new Employee(emp[0].Trim(), Int32.Parse(emp[1].Trim()), Decimal.Parse(emp[2].Trim()), Double.Parse(emp[3].Trim()));
                
            Console.WriteLine(employeesArray);
```

В данный момент вот такой код(есть второй класс Employee c конструктором и Get/Set в основном).
List использовать нельзя так как должно быть сделано через массив.
В консоли сообщает что "Необработанное исключение: System.FormatException: Входная строка имела неверный формат."

Upd2.
Проблему решил с помощью IFormatProvider и CultureInfo
Всем спасибо кто откликнулся)

Comment: String.Split() ?

Comment: либо `string.Split()` либо регулярки

Comment: Да, я читал об этом методе, но не до конца понимаю как мне его реализовать.
Строку на две разделить могу, по слову могу вывести, но присвоить каждой переменной ее значение не понимаю как

Comment: В методы `Parse` добавьте параметр `FormatProvider`. Укажите там культуру `CultureInfo`, в которой десятичный разделитель равен точке.

Answer (score 0):

Ребята начали, помогите уже

```
String str = "Bruce Wayne,    123456, 25.88, 35.50";
String [] strArray = str.Spli(',');
String a = strArray[0].Trim();
int b = Int32.Parse(strArray[1].Trim());
decimal c = Decimal.Parse(strArray[2].Trim());
double d = Double.Parse(strArray[3].Trim());
```

Это по вашему примеру. А на самом деле вам из вашего файла нужно спрасить массив объектов и его уже сортировать и делать что угодно. Посмотрите про парсинн csv файлов в объекты.